# Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have updated support libraries to version 23.0.1 and started getting this error.

**Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList.**

I have used many third party libraries in the application.Would that cause this issue?

**Gradle file:**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://maven.stickerpipe.com/artifactory/stickerfactory' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile 'com.cesarferreira.colorize:library:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.instabug.library:instabugsupport:1+'
    compile('vc908.stickers:stickerfactory:0.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile('com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
            }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Android Studio 2.0. I updated my dependencies that weren't current and now it is running fine.

By cross referencing our gradle files, I believe that you need to update your design support library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Answer (score 11):

I downgraded appcompat-v7 from:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

to:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Somebody answered to set higher version while somebody says lower version. This is because gradle uses upper version *silently* even if you defined as `23.1.1`. (At this time, it uses `24.0.1` to compile)

I recommend you to check correct version is involved by `gradlew app:dependencies -q` command.

To fix its upper version handover, set `force = true` to all of support libraries as below.

```
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'){
    force = true;
}
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'){
    force = true;
}
compile ('com.android.support:design:23.1.1'){
    force = true;
}
compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'){
    force = true;
}
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'){
    force = true;
}
```

Comment: I made sure that I've used everywhere the same support library version (24.0.0) and it still didn't work until I just replaced all the places were TintManager was used with AppCompatDrawableManager.
Seems that they have replaced TintManager with AppCompatDrawableManager becase [here][1] AppCompatDrawableManager has still tag TintManager.

  [1]: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/62eb3105e51335cf9074a5506d8d2b220aeb95dc/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatDrawableManager.java

Answer (score 1):

There are some combinations of libraries and tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the android-support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular a version lower than your target sdk version.)

Answer (score 0):

The **Support V4 library** serves as the base of much of the Android Support Library and contains many of the classes focused on making backward compatibility much easier.

**Try adding**

```
com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0
```

Comment: Tried it ,but did not work.Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

When using Tabs with Viewpager, it causes problem:
So making a solution to it, try by downgrading your support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1 to 23.2.0 or just decrease it by one at last digit.
I found the solution, hope you also get it. :)