# Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager"

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Since yesterday my app works not because of this error. I've been trying to find a solution but I have not found anything that has been achieved. 
For all I've modified my build.gradle to been to add two new libraries, but do not think that's the reason for the failure.

build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0' // http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.0'
```

error log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager;

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList
```

The error occurs in all fragments where I have a **TabLayout**.

If any have idea please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046525/didnt-find-class-android-support-v7-internal-widget-tintmanager-on-path-dexp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the problem by removing one of the new libraries introduced, did not think that was the problem, but it worked

Comment: Guys Don't remove library just try to maintain supportively compiled library should be common support libraries.
Ex appcompat, support

Answer (score 3):

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

You need to make the **appcompat** and the **design** the same Version.It doesn't mean you should make these same with the **buildToolsVersion**.My buildToolsVersion is "23.0.3".

Answer (score 0):

You to enable Multi-Dex, adding new lib. added more classes and methods for sure, so you probably ran out of the 65k Limit.