# TabLayout crash when compile a library in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-tablayout

I’m trying to use an image edition library and after compiling, I get an error in the activities with any TabLayout. Is this a library bug or its me? I’ve never seen this before.

Here is the error log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.runator-1/base.apk"]
```

This is the image edition library: https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop

If any have idea please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion?

Comment: targetSdkVersion -> 23
minSdkVersion -> 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't use the TintManager for our UCrop library

try to add:
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
or
com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0

be sure you use the latest version

More info here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34081829/2769065

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the info, its found!