# TabLayout with ViewPager leading to app crash

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to make a GUI for android app where I have TabLayout for separate fragments. Uptil now my MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml look like this:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.cortana.testing.activity;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.cortana.testing.R;


import com.example.cortana.testing.fragments.Fragment_A;
import com.example.cortana.testing.fragments.Fragment_B;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_A(), "A");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_B(), "B");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill" >
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Other things (fragments and their layouts) have been properly setup. Now, the problem is that when I include the tablayout with viewPager using the funtion `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` present on `line 44` of MainActivity.java, the app crashes. App doesn't crash and runs as expected (without tabs on the bar but fragments present). 
The app crash report is here:

```
06-23 11:23:05.949 21271-21271/com.example.cortana.testing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.cortana.testing, PID: 21271
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager;
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1145)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:635)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:669)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:365)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:340)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:624)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:595)
at com.example.cortana.testing.activity.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
at com.example.cortana.testing.activity.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
at com.example.cortana.testing.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:0)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6220)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4324)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_bb0868973057e0c4594582a2b34966b1571b4498-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_0380fc8cb59e96244f130184574ead0ab4fa81a6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.4.0_222d58f6b3309dd767eaedd78b101df07bb0214b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.4.0_d9254cdfbfc7a83fc69750e7bacf0c28659d5fbe-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-design-23.0.1_e104774034c64e7848d1f2ca9937e0b0ba73cbda-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.4.0_9c2b828fb5b4db0ad04d9c69d99c765617e6767c-classes.dex", dex 
    06-23 11:23:05.950 21271-21271/com.example.cortana.testing D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    06-23 11:23:05.950 21271-21271/com.example.cortana.testing D/Error: ERR: exMsg=Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_bb0868973057e0c4594582a2b34966b1571b4498-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_0380fc8cb59e96244f130184574ead0ab4fa81a6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.4.0_222d58f6b3309dd767eaedd78b101df07bb0214b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.4.0_d9254cdfbfc7a83fc69750e7bacf0c28659d5fbe-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-design-23.0.1_e104774034c64e7848d1f2ca9937e0b0ba73cbda-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.4.0_9c2b828fb5b4db0ad04d9c69d99c765617e6767c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0_295f5bae1ae17fe25c8f6037cf5499452801adbf-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
    06-23 11:23:05.950 21271-21271/com.example.cortana.testing D/Error: ERR: file=BaseDexClassLoader.java
    06-23 11:23:05.950 21271-21271/com.example.cortana.testing D/Error: ERR: class=dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader
    06-23 11:23:05.950 21271-21271/com.example.cortana.testing D/Error: ERR: method=findClass line=56
    06-23 11:23:05.951 21271-21271/com.example.cortana.testing D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager;
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1145)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:635)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:669)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:365)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:340)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:624)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:595)
at com.example.cortana.testing.activity.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
at com.example.cortana.testing.activity.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
at com.example.cortana.testing.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:0)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6220)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4324)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_bb0868973057e0c4594582a2b34966b1571b4498-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_0380fc8cb59e96244f130184574ead0ab4fa81a6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.4.0_222d58f6b3309dd767eaedd78b101df07bb0214b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.4.0_d9254cdfbfc7a83fc69750e7bacf0c28659d5fbe-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-design-23.0.1_e104774034c64e7848d1f2ca9937e0b0ba73cbda-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.4.0_9c2b828fb5b4db0ad04d9c69d99c765617e6767c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.cortana.testing/files/instant-run/dex/sl
06-23 11:23:05.951 21271-21271/com.example.cortana.testing D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 21616
06-23 11:23:07.877 21271-21271/com.example.cortana.testing I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21271 SIG: 9
```

I dont know why this is happening. What should I do to resolve it? Also please include the reason of this crash.

Edit: I have included the library `compile com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` in the build.gradle but its still giving the exact same error. I have cleaned the project and then rebuilt it. 
The build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cortana.testing"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

EDIT 2:

I have installed the same version of libraries and it still wont work. Can someone please suggest some other ideas. 
As I told before, the function thats tripping everything up is `tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`. If I comment it out, the app works fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046525/didnt-find-class-android-support-v7-internal-widget-tintmanager-on-path-dexp

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast answer

Comment: Try to clean your project first, then run. If still not working, try to update your design support library. Be aware that sometimes 'Instant Run' feature in android studio will behave incorretly and make your project not working.

Comment: I have included the design class in manifest and its still crashing with same errors. And where was the clean project button in android studio again :|

Comment: On Menu Build, select Clean Project

Comment: Thanks. I have tried cleaning up and then rebuilding with new versions of lib. Hasn't helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the classloader cannot find the class *android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager*.

You'll probably need to add this to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
```

By the way, you should not mix versions of the support library. I saw you edited your post to include:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Don't do this (mix 23.4.0 and 23.1.1). Either use 23.4.0 or 23.1.1. Preferably, use the latest (24.0.0 at this moment) since it solves many bugs.

Don't forget to do a "Refresh all gradle projects" afterwards.
[image]

PS: ow yeah, @arya-stark, please stay away from The Hound ;-)

Comment: I think hound and I are chill. And then I know how to "stick them with the pointy end" :)

Comment: @aryastark I saw your update, you shouldn't mix versions of the support library. See also my updated answer.

Comment: I have tried doing that and it didnt help . Please check out the update

Comment: @aryastark Did you do a "Refresh all gradle projects" (see my updated answer)?

Comment: No I hadn't done that. Thanks, that worked. Guess grade wasn't getting updated for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The version of support library and design library should be the same.

Like

```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

or try it..

```
android {
 ........ 
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
 ..........
    }
```

I hope it work...

Comment: Yes, I got it the first time and have tried it. Doesn't help.